# What are the formulas for calculating Attack & Defence when battling in Age of Legends?

Tags: age-of-legends

When battling another player in Age of Legends, your Attack value (or defense value when being attacked) is calculated off of the size of your guild, plus some factor applied to your Attack/Defense values accumulated from your weapons.

What is the exact formula that is used to calculate your Attack or Defense.

Please note, this game is made by Uken Games which has quite a few games that are exactly the same but with different themes (i.e. Dark Galaxies, Heroes and Villians, etc.)  If you know the formulas for any of the other Uken Games, please post that as a potential answer because it is most likely correct.

Comment: I wish I knew, could someone from Uken answer this question please.

Comment: Uken would probably not tell for various reasons, but I am hoping that someone out there has either figured it out by studying the minor changes that happen when you set your attribute points or when you buy/sell items and level.